# показать/скрыть меню

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код, где 'open_menu' - это кнопка (ссылка) , а 'header_menu' - меню. При нажатии на кнопку меню должно появляться, и при повторном нажатии исчезать. Но вместо этого сама кнопка появляется и исчезает, без клика на нее (как анимация). Подскажите, где ошибка, пожалуйста.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open_menu").toggle(function() { 
    $(".header_menu").fadeIn();
    return false;
  },  
  function() { 
    $(".header_menu").fadeOut();
    return false;
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Найдите дубликат кто-нибудь

Comment: версия jquery какая?

Comment: Версия Jquery 3.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В  toggle http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ нет вариант использования функции toggle(callback, callback), изучите подробнее этот метод. Правильно, например, так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".open_menu").on('click', function() {
        $(".header_menu").toggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" value="Меню" class="open_menu">
  <div class="header_menu">Блок меню</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Впредь буду внимателен

Answer (score 1):

Или так, если надо с `fade`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".open_menu").on('click', function() {
        $(".header_menu").fadeToggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" value="Меню" class="open_menu">
  <div class="header_menu">Блок меню</div>

</body>

</html>
```