# По клику открыть меню

Tags: jquery

Нужно чтобы по клику (в нашем случае) на букву "М" появлялось под-меню, а при повторном клике исчезало, реализовать это с помощью jquery было бы просто замечательно.
Изначально под-меню скрыто с помощью `display: none;`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XyXgpK

Comment: на сайте есть [поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E). Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь им пользоваться.

Comment: дубликат - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так на вашем примере)

```js
  $(function() {
      $(".show__phones").on('click', function() {
        $(".hide__phones").toggle();
      });
    });
```

```css
.contacts__with__us {
 display: flex;
}
.phones__main__info {
 position: relative;
}
.phone {
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.show__phones:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.hide__phones {
  display: none;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.hide__phones span:first-child {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contacts__with__us">
     <div class="phones__block v-c">
      <div class="phones__main__info">
       <span class="phone">0(800) 215 350</span>
              <a class="show__phones"><span>M</span></a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="hide__phones">
       <span>0 (099) 215 350</span>
       <span>0 (099) 215 350</span>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```